# how to using instagram json on laravel?

Tags: json, laravel

Looks like https://www.instagram.com/nike/media/ providing json format. Is it right? I am not sure. If it is json format, how to display on laravel blate template?

```
Controller
$url = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/nike/media/');
$json = json_decode($url);
dd($json)
```

If I do like this on controller, arrays are coming out.

```
{#493 ▼
 +"items": array:20 [▼
0 => {#203 ▶}
1 => {#228 ▶}
2 => {#242 ▶}
3 => {#256 ▶}
4 => {#268 ▶}
5 => {#280 ▶}
6 => {#296 ▶}
7 => {#308 ▶}
8 => {#322 ▶}
9 => {#336 ▶}
10 => {#350 ▶}
11 => {#364 ▶}
12 => {#378 ▶}
13 => {#391 ▶}
14 => {#405 ▶}
15 => {#419 ▶}
16 => {#439 ▶}
17 => {#453 ▶}
18 => {#466 ▶}
19 => {#480 ▶}
 ]
 +"more_available": true
 +"status": "ok"
}
```

I don't know how to write on blade template.

I want to display instagram photos without any authentication

If this is wrong, is there any way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, JSON also have arrays. Each array from the item object contains one of the picture from the account.

Passing the json variable to your template, you would use it like so, to display the thumbnails (for example):

```
@foreach($json->items as $item)
    <img src="{{ $item->images->thumbnail->url }}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: @KevinSwiss if it is working, you should be accepting the answer as correct.